# CSS: Centre image and text vertically in a div

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically centre an image and some text in the middle of a single div (like the logo and site name at the top of the webpage). The image will be on the left with some padding around it, and the text will be right next to the image and also positioned vertically centrally in the div.

This image visualises the outcome:

> [image]

I've tried many codes from all over the internet, but can't get it to work. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html - All you need to know about vertical align

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just a small addition to [**João's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988502/1494505) (can't post comments):*

---

When you are using a `<h1>` tag you should add the following to your `<h1>` tag:

```
display: inline;
vertical-align: middle;
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy22f/2/)**

**Multiline compatible: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy22f/9/)** *added*

Just adding `display: inline-block;` will not position the text correctly.

Comment: So the text doesn't need to be multi-line and remain vertically centered??

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to your image. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy22f/3/) exemplifying it.

Comment: It only works if the text size is the normal one. For texts for various sizes/fonts, this does not work. For example, a <h1>Title</h1>  would have to work too.

Comment: You need to make it behave like an inline element, by adding `display: inline-block` to your `h1`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/gy22f/6/

I used display table & table-cell to make vertical-align works properly.

Answer (score -1):

try this: it worked for me

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;">
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td style="margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;border:1px solid black">
                        <img src="http://www.instablogsimages.com/images/2008/01/16/vw-logo-img-routan-van_5965.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" alt=""/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;border:1px solid black;">
                            Some Text
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: **Noooooooo!** No tables for layout!

Comment: [Why not to use tables for layout in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)